# reactjs - send parameter to function on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        countries: [{code: 'aa', name: 'abc'}, {code: 'bb', name: 'bbb'}]
    }
  }

  setCountry(country) {
    console.log(country);
  }

  render() {
    var countriesList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.countries.length; i++) {
        var code = this.state.countries[i].code;
        var name = this.state.countries[i].name;
        countriesList.push(
            <li key={i} onClick={() => this.setCountry({code: code, name: name})}>
                <span>
                    <img src={"/assets/images/country/" + code + ".jpg"} alt={code} title={code} /> {name}
                </span>
            </li>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="wrap">
            <ul>{countriesList}</ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that whatever I click (onclick event on li - render function) it seems to send same parameter (corresponding to last element of the array). Any idea what that happens?

Comment: all the elements include same key?

Comment: i is in loop, as variable. is not the same.

Comment: so the code and name should be different, otherwise your array include the same codes and names

Comment: yes, they are. and they look different (the image is different and correct, so is the name). I thought maybe I send something as reference but I tried sending the loop variable (simple integer) and had same issue (always logs the last).

Comment: so in setCountry() the console.log shows the same data (the last) for all the records in the list?

Comment: yes, it always prints last element code and name. (in that case {code: 'bb', name: 'bbb'})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a function within a loop. When you click on the button, till then the loop has finished executing. So the `code` and `name` variable are pointing to the last iteration value. So whenever you click on any element, it will pass last values of `code` and `name`. You can avoid that by using `map` function like this

```
this.state.countries.map((country, i) => {
      var code = country.code;
      var name = country.name;
      countriesList.push(
        <li key={i} onClick={() => this.setCountry({ code: code, name: name })}>
          <span>
            <img src={"/assets/images/country/" + code + ".jpg"} alt={code} title={code} /> {name}
          </span>
        </li>
      );
    })
```

This is a common problem. I recommend you to use [linter rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func) to avoid this problem in future.

Comment: @zozo The linter rule I just added in the answer has an example which shows the problem. Also read about `closures`.

Comment: @zb22 Because that thing is executed with the loop. So they take value during the iteration. But `onClick` handler executes when that thing is clicked. Till then the loop is completed and `code` and `name` point to last iteration value. So it takes those values.

Comment: @ Prakash sharma, yeah explanation in ESLint very usefull